# Search Filter in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an responsive container for users. I made a simple filtering that will show list of user depend on their **Id**.

## Current

```js
let data = [
    {Id:'123',Name:'John Doe',Gender:'Male'},
    {Id:'213',Name:'Wilma Gil',Gender:'Female'}, 
    {Id:'312',Name:'Peter Lee',Gender:'Male'},
    {Id:'421',Name:'Chezka Ong',Gender:'Female'}
];
function filter(){
    let input = document.getElementById("search").value;
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    container.appendChild(div);
    if(input === null || input === ''){
            console.log('empty');
    }else{
        for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(data[i].Id.includes(input)){
                div.innerHTML += `
                    <p>Id: ${data[i]['Id']}</p>
                    <p>Name: ${data[i]['Name']}</p>
                    <p>Gender: ${data[i]['Gender']}</p>
                `
                container.appendChild(div);
                console.log(data[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
html { font-size: 22px; }
body { padding: 1rem; }
#search {
    background-image: url('magnify.svg');
    background-position: 5px 5px 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
button {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}
.container > div{
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search..">
<button onClick="filter()">Test</button>
<div id="container" class="container">
</div>
```

Now, I'm getting the data and it show in my HTML file. **BUT** the problem is, every time it will show data, it will shrink in one div. It seems that I'm missing something.

I want is when I search *Id* have the same with other user it will show in my html data **in separate div**. Currently, all data is merged in one div.

## Want to achieve(*sample search: '12' will show... )

```css
html { font-size: 22px; }
body { padding: 1rem; }
#search {
    background-image: url('magnify.svg');
    background-position: 5px 5px 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
button {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}
.container > div{
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search.." value="12">
<button onClick="filter()">Test</button>
<div id="container" class="container">
    <div><p>Id: 123</p><p>Name: John Doe</p><p>Gender: Male</p></div>
    <div><p>Id: 312</p><p>Name: Peter Lee</p><p>Gender: Male</p></div>
</div>
```

If you can help me to figure out this, It helps a lot.

Comment: Please edit again and make a [mcve] - the last example does not work because filter is not defined. It is not clear what your expected result is

Comment: @mplungjan. Already edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `let div = document.createElement("div");` INSIDE the loop

But here is a much simpler version

```js
let data = [
    {Id:'123',Name:'John Doe',Gender:'Male'},
    {Id:'213',Name:'Wilma Gil',Gender:'Female'}, 
    {Id:'312',Name:'Peter Lee',Gender:'Male'},
    {Id:'421',Name:'Chezka Ong',Gender:'Female'}
];

const inputField = document.getElementById("search");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

const filter = () => {
  const input = inputField.value;
  container.innerHTML = "";
  if (input === null || input === '') {
    console.log('empty');
    return;
  }
  container.innerHTML = data
    .filter(({Id}) => Id.includes(input))
    .map(({ Id, Name, Gender }) => `
      <div class="person">
        <p>Id: ${Id}</p>
        <p>Name: ${Name}</p>
        <p>Gender: ${Gender}</p>
      </div>`)
    .join("");
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 22px;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

#search {
  background-image: url('magnify.svg');
  background-position: 5px 5px 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.container>div {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search..">
<button onClick="filter()">Test</button>
<div id="container" class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps me a lot and made my code simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Move `let div = document.createElement("div");` inside the else function so you create div only when the `id` matches. Basically it will create a new `div`. Also change the the css grid from column to row

```js
let data = [{
    Id: '123',
    Name: 'John Doe',
    Gender: 'Male'
  },
  {
    Id: '213',
    Name: 'Wilma Gil',
    Gender: 'Female'
  },
  {
    Id: '312',
    Name: 'Peter Lee',
    Gender: 'Male'
  },
  {
    Id: '421',
    Name: 'Chezka Ong',
    Gender: 'Female'
  },
  {
    Id: '123',
    Name: 'John Doe',
    Gender: 'Male'
  },
];

function filter() {
  let input = document.getElementById("search").value;
  let container = document.getElementById("container");
  //let div = document.createElement("div");
  //container.appendChild(div);
  if (input === null || input === '') {
    console.log('empty');
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].Id.includes(input)) {
        let div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML += `
                    <p>Id: ${data[i]['Id']}</p>
                    <p>Name: ${data[i]['Name']}</p>
                    <p>Gender: ${data[i]['Gender']}</p>
                `
        container.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 22px;
}

body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

#search {
  background-image: url('magnify.svg');
  background-position: 5px 5px 5px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-auto-flow: row; // changed here
}

.container>div {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search..">
<button onClick="filter()">Test</button>
<div id="container" class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: If that is all you changed, you could have commented and voted to close as typo-type...

Comment: I see. Thank you. I though there's no problem with my code tough.